# What is prerequisite to create Universal App in Visual Studio?

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I want to create universal app which can work in Windows 8 Desktop and Windows phone 8 and higher version.

Can anybody suggest what tools I should use?

Visual Studio - Version?

Any special plug in with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 you'll need **Visual Studio 2012** or higher.
Just check the project templates for the desired project type:

[image]

**However:**
Please note that your so called "*higher versions*" will only work up to Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1.

If you want to create and deploy the same app for Windows 10, you have to use **Visual Studio 2015**!

Comment: Is it possible to create single application which can have single UI with single share code and it can support all windows device(expect xbox) for both operating system windows 8 and windows 10?

Comment: @NJBhanushali As far as I know, there is one migration path from Windows 8(.1?) solutions (Phone project, Desktop project and Shared project) to Windows 10 solutions keeping the project structure. This may work, but some controls are not supported any longer in Windows 10 (either obsolete or removed). You could give that a try, but there's no guarantee it'll work out the way you want. You'll most likely will be able to support phone and desktop then, but no other device types.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop some uni apps for windows 8/8.1, you can you Visual Studio 2012 or higher. For desktop applications, you can use only WPF or WinForms, but I suppose, you go for Metro apps.